# How long have greencard holders to move in the USA?

Tags: usa, greencard, relocation

I have a greencard but I can't find a job in the US so I have never worked there or moved. I just entered with the inmigrant visa snd then received the card in the mail.

Comment: Why would there be any restriction on your movement?

Comment: I think the question is, how long does anyone have to move to the USA once they get their PR status.

Comment: @edocetirwi I think "I just entered with the immigrant visa and then received the card in the mail" means that the OP has already arrived in the US and received the PR ("green") card.  Note that being approved for, or receiving, an immigrant visa does not confer PR status; that only happens when the immigrant is admitted to the US with the immigrant visa.

Answer (score 2):

You become a permanent resident the moment you enter with your immigrant visa.  As a permanent resident, you can move wherever you want, whenever you want.

(If you're talking about moving *outside* the US, there's no restriction on the timing of this move, but there *are* restrictions on the length of time you may remain out of the country without losing your permanent resident status. You can apply for permission to exceed these limits.)

Comment: Note that while you have the freedom to move, after you move you are required to report your new address with [Form AR-11](https://www.uscis.gov/addresschange).